# Codeigniter unlink session unavailable

Tags: php, codeigniter, single-sign-on

I have multiple codeigniter application folder with single login (shared session name and domain) to implement simple sso,

it works fine but sometimes when multiple application open in same browser and access request in the same time in server produce error like this, that cause all application keep loading until the user clear browser cookie and cache and login again

> unlink(C:\xampp71\tmp\sso_sessionvarnfnkgiu1aml10tob2f2vgubgphjtf):
>   Resource temporarily unavailable
>   C:\xampp71\htdocs\sso\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php
>   386

Comment: make a common session storage folder and point all CI application to that session storage, then it would work fine.

Comment: what matter with default web server session storage location?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you need to set the folder permission or you can change the folder directory which already has permission. So the easy solution is to set the folder path in your configuration file. `config.php` which is located in `/application/config/config.php`. You can see the session configuration like below

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

You need set the folder path for your session files. To set the folder path you need to set the value of `$config['sess_save_path']`which is currently set to `NULL`. You can set the value as below:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache';
```

I am using the cache folder your can use any folder you want but make sure that folder has permission.

As result you will not see “Session – Unlink Operation Not Permitted” anymore.

Comment: I'm using windows as server, the problem is not permission but the session file is missing when some application try to update session I think (I used multiple CI with same session setting to implement Single Sign On)